# bigbluebutton webhooks checksumError

Tags: webhooks, bigbluebutton

I want create bigbluebutton webhoock, but "checksum" it's not correct

```
<?php
    $urljoin ="https://server1.example.com/bigbluebutton/api/hooks/create?";
    $params ='callbackURL=' .urlencode('http://example.net');
echo $urljoin.$params.'&checksum='.sha1('create'.$params.'S8BFPSCuY6XTghtr3iuNrOJhCKMJEV0W0dkfppjow');
}
```

please guide me
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your code is having several issues. Here is the code that you can refer to.

```
$bbb_url = "https://your_domain/bigbluebutton";
$bbb_secret = "YOUR_BBB_SECRET";
$api_name = "create";
$parameter = "name=Test&meetingID=test01";
$checksum = sha1($api_name . $parameter . $bbb_secret);

$query = $parameter . "&checksum=" . $checksum;

$url = $bbb_url . "/api/" . $api_name . "?" . $query;

header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: $url");
```

Check the official document for more help about create API call: https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/dev/api.html#create